# How to get air tight seals on canisters?

Tags: kitchen, air

I'm looking into buying some cheap canisters for my kitchen such as this

[image]

I'm unsure if this has a rubber seal in the lid already to make it air tight so I was wondering if there was a simple way to do this myself just in case it doesn't?

I have seen a few copper canisters that are for the bathrooms and they don't have a rubber/cork seal in them so I would need to know how I can do it myself.

Answer (score 3):

Place a sheet of plastic wrap over the container before placing the lid on top. This will meet between the rubber and the container to ensure an air-tight seal.

Comment: The problem is that I'm unsure whether there is a rubber seal at all so want I want to know is if there is a way to attach my own seal

Comment: @SaturnsEye Multiple layers of plastic wrap will still work.

Answer (score 2):

If you're primarily drawn to these canisters because they look nice, you could put things in Ziploc bags and put the bags into the containers.  (Just like breakfast cereal: it's usually in a more airtight plastic bag, inside a sturdier, decorative box.)

A similar approach, which I don't like as much, is to buy smaller hermitic containers that fit inside the decorative brass ones, and store the contents in the smaller containers which are then inside the brass containers.

Answer (score 1):

I understand your question to if it is possible to modify an arbitrary copper cannister to be air right. That is a rather large question...

Depending on your skills and how nice you want it to look I'd say: *Yes, to some extent and to a certain level of air tight*.

To me the easiest and prettiest method would be to line the lid or the top of the cannister with tape or rubber of some sort if they are too wide.

If you use a flexible liner material it will be quite air tight, and you could possibly get it even better using the plastic wrap tip from another answer.

Answer (score -1):

Try to find a rubber [O-ring](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/O-ring) that fits the diameter of the lid. Then just slide it on the lip of the lid, on the area that fits inside the can. Then push down. That should seal it.